# Logstash date filter don’t parse time

Tags: logstash

I have a log in msi installer format (time only, without date):

```
MSI (c) (F0:8C) [09:00:05:007]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (F0:8C) [09:00:05:007]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (F0:8C) [09:00:05:007]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (F0:8C) [09:00:05:007]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (F0:8C) [09:00:05:007]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
```

I want to get a time substring from the log and merge it with the current date.
This is my filters config:

```
filter {
  if "curl" in [tags] {
    date {
      locale => "en"
      match => ["message", "HH:mm:ss:SSS"]
      timezone => "+0200"
      target => "logtime"
    }
    mutate {
         add_field => {"logdate" => "%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"}
         add_field => {"tmp_field" => "%{logdate}_%{logtime}"}
    }
    date {
      locale => "en"
      match => ["tmp_field", "YYYY-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss:SSS"]
      timezone => "+0200"
      remove_field => ["logdate","logtime","tmp_field"]
    }
  }
}
```

When loading logs into logstash, the filter does not work and I get the _dateparsefailure tag for each event.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, you will need to isolate timestamp, in your case without date, using `grok` or something like that. Then you can try to parse it with `date` and start adding date. Something like this:

```
filter {
    grok {
        break_on_match => false
        match => ["message","MSI \(c\) \((?<id>[A-F0-9]{2}:[A-F0-9]{2})\) \[%{TIME:time}\]: %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
        tag_on_failure => [ "_grokparsefailure"]
        add_field => { "time" => "%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"}
        add_field => { "timestamp" => "%{time} %{hour}" }
    }
    date {
        target => "@timestamp"
        match => ["timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
        timezone => "+0200"
    }
}
```

Disclaimer, this is not tested, it's an idea, there might be some minor errors, but it's a general way to go for this issue.